# Increase width and height of position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I have a circle element (`a` element) with `position: absolute` and CSS3 transition. On the `hover` event, I want to increase both height and width of the circle but I want to add pixels to all sides not only in left side or right side.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/xWCp2/

In above example, you can observe that increasing height and width will add pixels to the left and bottom side of the circle, not all sides.

How can I address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element must be `position: absolute`, then you'll have to account for the change in size by adjusting its position when hovered.

For example: if you're going from a width and height of 20px to a width and height of 30px, you'll need to change the top and right positions by 5px less, to keep it relative to the circle's center point.

**A better way** of doing this would be with CSS transforms.

```
.circle-item:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this lines to hover, with values half of width/height change:

```
margin-top: -5px;
margin-right: -5px;
```

JSF: http://jsfiddle.net/xWCp2/6/

With padding-top, you can force the content to stay in place:

```
padding-top: 5px;
```

JSF: http://jsfiddle.net/xWCp2/8/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have that extra class in your original CSS which isn't always applied.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/xWCp2/7/)

**CSS**

```
.circle-item.small {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    border: 3px solid #7f8c8d;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);    
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    line-height: 20px;

}

.circle-item.small:hover {
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```